# Global using variables definition and declaration in C++

Tags: c++

I am beginer in C++ programing language and i want to learn how to use all my variables in every single part of project in C++ (separate .cpp files or classes...).
For example, if we make comparation to Fortran, in Fortran we can make declaration or definition of variables in one module and we can use that module for sharing variables in main program or any other module. What concept from C++ is equivalent to concept of modules in Fortran?

Comment: I recommend not using global variables at all.

Comment: First learn the difference between *definition* and *declaration*, and about [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)). Then you will know how to *define* a variable in the global scope (outside any namespace, class or function) in one translation unit, and *declare* it in another. With that said, avoid global variables as much as you can. Instead pass data and variables as *arguments* to functions you call.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ equivalent to Fortran's modules is namespaces.

Have a look over there to learn more about [namespaces](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace).

Namespace introduces the idea of scope:

```
namespace V { // original-namespace-definition for V
    void f(); // declaration of V::f
  }
  void V::f() {} // definition of V::f
  void f() {} // declaration and definition of f() # different from V::f()
```